pylsp + vim.lsp.buf.format not working
require'lspconfig'.pylsp.setup {
    settings = {
        pylsp = {
            plugins = {
                autopep8 = {enabled = false},
                black = {enabled = true},
                flake8 = {enabled = false},
                pycodestyle = {enabled = false, maxLineLength = 6},
                pyflakes = {enabled = false},
                yapf = {enabled = false},
                pylint = {enabled = false}
            }
        }
    }
}

!vim.lsp.buf.format()
nothing happens...
LSP server capabilities
definitionProvider = true,
  documentFormattingProvider = true,
  documentHighlightProvider = true,
  documentOnTypeFormattingProvider = {
    firstTriggerCharacter = "\n"
  },
  documentRangeFormattingProvider = true,
  documentSymbolProvider = true,
  executeCommandProvider = {
    commands = { "lua.removeSpace", "lua.solve", "lua.jsonToLua", "lua.setConfig", "lua.getConfig", "lua.autoRequire" }
  },

LSP Log
[START][2024-04-26 12:07:55] LSP logging initiated
[INFO][2024-04-26 12:07:55] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:662 "Starting RPC client"   {  args = {},  cmd = "/home/t/.local/bin/pylsp",  extra = {    cwd = "/home/t/lab/code/python/perm"  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:55] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:284    "rpc.send"  {  id = 1,  jsonrpc = "2.0",  method = "initialize",  params = {    capabilities = {      textDocument = {        callHierarchy = {          dynamicRegistration = false        },        codeAction = {          codeActionLiteralSupport = {            codeActionKind = {              valueSet = { "", "quickfix", "refactor", "refactor.extract", "refactor.inline", "refactor.rewrite", "source", "source.organizeImports" }            }          },          dataSupport = true,          dynamicRegistration = false,          isPreferredSupport = true,          resolveSupport = {            properties = { "edit" }          }        },        completion = {          completionItem = {            commitCharactersSupport = false,            deprecatedSupport = false,            documentationFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" },            preselectSupport = false,            snippetSupport = false          },          completionItemKind = {            valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 }          },          contextSupport = false,          dynamicRegistration = false        },        declaration = {          linkSupport = true        },        definition = {          linkSupport = true        },        documentHighlight = {          dynamicRegistration = false        },        documentSymbol = {          dynamicRegistration = false,          hierarchicalDocumentSymbolSupport = true,          symbolKind = {            valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 }          }        },        hover = {          contentFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" },          dynamicRegistration = false        },        implementation = {          linkSupport = true        },        publishDiagnostics = {          relatedInformation = true,          tagSupport = {            valueSet = { 1, 2 }          }        },        references = {          dynamicRegistration = false        },        rename = {          dynamicRegistration = false,          prepareSupport = true        },        semanticTokens = {          augmentsSyntaxTokens = true,          dynamicRegistration = false,          formats = { "relative" },          multilineTokenSupport = false,          overlappingTokenSupport = true,          requests = {            full = {              delta = true            },            range = false          },          serverCancelSupport = false,          tokenModifiers = { "declaration", "definition", "readonly", "static", "deprecated", "abstract", "async", "modification", "documentation", "defaultLibrary" },          tokenTypes = { "namespace", "type", "class", "enum", "interface", "struct", "typeParameter", "parameter", "variable", "property", "enumMember", "event", "function", "method", "macro", "keyword", "modifier", "comment", "string", "number", "regexp", "operator", "decorator" }        },        signatureHelp = {          dynamicRegistration = false,          signatureInformation = {            activeParameterSupport = true,            documentationFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" },            parameterInformation = {              labelOffsetSupport = true            }          }        },        synchronization = {          didSave = true,          dynamicRegistration = false,          willSave = true,          willSaveWaitUntil = true        },        typeDefinition = {          linkSupport = true        }      },      window = {        showDocument = {          support = true        },        showMessage = {          messageActionItem = {            additionalPropertiesSupport = false          }        },        workDoneProgress = true      },      workspace = {        applyEdit = true,        configuration = true,        didChangeWatchedFiles = {          dynamicRegistration = false,          relativePatternSupport = true        },        semanticTokens = {          refreshSupport = true        },        symbol = {          dynamicRegistration = false,          hierarchicalWorkspaceSymbolSupport = true,          symbolKind = {            valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 }          }        },        workspaceEdit = {          resourceOperations = { "rename", "create", "delete" }        },        workspaceFolders = true      }    },    clientInfo = {      name = "Neovim",      version = "0.9.5"    },    initializationOptions = vim.empty_dict(),    processId = 276167,    rootPath = "/home/t/lab/code/python/perm",    rootUri = "file:///home/t/lab/code/python/perm",    trace = "off",    workspaceFolders = { {        name = "/home/t/lab/code/python/perm",        uri = "file:///home/t/lab/code/python/perm"      } }  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:55] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:387    "rpc.receive"   {  id = 1,  jsonrpc = "2.0",  result = {    capabilities = {      codeActionProvider = true,      codeLensProvider = {        resolveProvider = false      },      completionProvider = {        resolveProvider = true,        triggerCharacters = { "." }      },      definitionProvider = true,      documentFormattingProvider = true,      documentHighlightProvider = true,      documentRangeFormattingProvider = true,      documentSymbolProvider = true,      executeCommandProvider = {        commands = {}      },      experimental = vim.empty_dict(),      foldingRangeProvider = true,      hoverProvider = true,      notebookDocumentSync = {        notebookSelector = { {            cells = { {                language = "python"              } }          } }      },      referencesProvider = true,      renameProvider = true,      signatureHelpProvider = {        triggerCharacters = { "(", ",", "=" }      },      textDocumentSync = {        change = 2,        openClose = true,        save = {          includeText = true        }      },      workspace = {        workspaceFolders = {          changeNotifications = true,          supported = true        }      }    },    serverInfo = {      name = "pylsp",      version = "1.11.0"    }  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:55] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:284    "rpc.send"  {  jsonrpc = "2.0",  method = "initialized",  params = vim.empty_dict()}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:55] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:284    "rpc.send"  {  jsonrpc = "2.0",  method = "workspace/didChangeConfiguration",  params = {    settings = {      pylsp = {        plugins = {          autopep8 = {            enabled = false          },          black = {            enabled = true          },          flake8 = {            enabled = false          },          pycodestyle = {            enabled = false,            maxLineLength = 6          },          pyflakes = {            enabled = false          },          pylint = {            enabled = false          },          yapf = {            enabled = false          }        }      }    }  }}
[INFO][2024-04-26 12:07:55] .../lua/vim/lsp.lua:1344    "LSP[pylsp]"    "server_capabilities"   {  server_capabilities = {    codeActionProvider = true,    codeLensProvider = {      resolveProvider = false    },    completionProvider = {      resolveProvider = true,      triggerCharacters = { "." }    },    definitionProvider = true,    documentFormattingProvider = true,    documentHighlightProvider = true,    documentRangeFormattingProvider = true,    documentSymbolProvider = true,    executeCommandProvider = {      commands = {}    },    experimental = vim.empty_dict(),    foldingRangeProvider = true,    hoverProvider = true,    notebookDocumentSync = {      notebookSelector = { {          cells = { {              language = "python"            } }        } }    },    referencesProvider = true,    renameProvider = true,    signatureHelpProvider = {      triggerCharacters = { "(", ",", "=" }    },    textDocumentSync = {      change = 2,      openClose = true,      save = {        includeText = true      }    },    workspace = {      workspaceFolders = {        changeNotifications = true,        supported = true      }    }  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:55] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:284    "rpc.send"  {  jsonrpc = "2.0",  method = "textDocument/didOpen",  params = {    textDocument = {      languageId = "python",      text = '# thislist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]\nthislist = ["a", "b", "c"]\nfix_index = [0, 0, 0]\nhoriz_index = [0, 0, 0]\ndepth = 0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n# print(thislist)\nwhile (depth > 0):\n    # depth > 3\n    -depth\n# list(\n',      uri = "file:///home/t/lab/code/python/perm/letters.py",      version = 0    }  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:56] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:387    "rpc.receive"   {  id = "ee5023bd-3731-48bc-97de-06dba39d159f",  jsonrpc = "2.0",  method = "window/workDoneProgress/create",  params = {    token = "900def12-a464-4517-829b-80c6759afe4a"  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:56] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:403    "server_request: callback result"   {  result = vim.NIL,  status = true}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:56] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:284    "rpc.send"  {  id = "ee5023bd-3731-48bc-97de-06dba39d159f",  jsonrpc = "2.0",  result = vim.NIL}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:56] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:387    "rpc.receive"   {  jsonrpc = "2.0",  method = "$/progress",  params = {    token = "900def12-a464-4517-829b-80c6759afe4a",    value = {      kind = "begin",      title = "lint: mccabe"    }  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:56] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:387    "rpc.receive"   {  jsonrpc = "2.0",  method = "$/progress",  params = {    token = "900def12-a464-4517-829b-80c6759afe4a",    value = {      kind = "end"    }  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:07:56] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:387    "rpc.receive"   {  jsonrpc = "2.0",  method = "textDocument/publishDiagnostics",  params = {    diagnostics = {},    uri = "file:///home/t/lab/code/python/perm/letters.py"  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:08:02] .../lua/vim/lsp.lua:1391   "LSP[pylsp]"    "client.request"    1   "textDocument/formatting"   {  options = {    insertSpaces = true,    tabSize = 4  },  textDocument = {    uri = "file:///home/t/lab/code/python/perm/letters.py"  }}   <function 1>    1
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:08:02] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:284    "rpc.send"  {  id = 2,  jsonrpc = "2.0",  method = "textDocument/formatting",  params = {    options = {      insertSpaces = true,      tabSize = 4    },    textDocument = {      uri = "file:///home/t/lab/code/python/perm/letters.py"    }  }}
[DEBUG][2024-04-26 12:08:02] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:387    "rpc.receive"   {  id = 2,  jsonrpc = "2.0"}}


I fear we don't have enough information to reproduce your problem. Maybe should you provide a minimal configuration and setup steps to reproduce your problem. Another alternative is to ask your question directly to the plugin github issue tracker(lspconfig or pylsp).
